# Uniqueness of solution for SDE with random coefficients

Tags: stochastic-differential-equations

Suppose we have a SDE in the form of
$$dX_t = f(t, X_t, W_t)dt + g(t)dW_t$$
In my case, I am able to find one solution for this equation. Is there any theorem which can prove that this solution is unique?

More specifically, my SDE is 
$$dX_t = (\mu - \sigma \beta Z_t)dt + \sigma \sqrt{1 + 2\beta t}dW_t $$
where $Z_t = e^{-\beta t}\int\limits_0^t{e^{\beta u}\sqrt{1+2\beta u}dW(u)}$, and therefore depends only on $W_t$. The solution is $X_t = X_0 + (\mu - \frac{\sigma^2}{2}(1 + \beta t)))t + \sigma Z_t$

All the existence and uniqueness theorems I have found are about diffusion SDE, and therefore require $f(t, X_t)$ and $g(t, X_t)$. What can be done if $f$ contains $W_t$ component?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but what if you redefine $X^1_t$ as your original SDE and $X^2_t$ as $W_t$.

Then rewrite it as a 2D diffusion SDE, with $X_t = (X^1_t,X^2_t)$. Let
$$
\mu = \begin{bmatrix} f(X_t,t)\\ 0 \end{bmatrix}
\;\;\;\;\&\;\;\;\;
\sigma = \begin{bmatrix} g(X_t,t)\\ 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
So now you have a 2D SDE:
$$
dX_t = \mu(X_t,t)\,dt + \sigma(X_t,t)\,dW_t
$$
which is a standard Ito process.

Now you can maybe apply the multi-dimensional versions of the existence and uniqueness lemmas (e.g. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_differential_equation#Existence_and_uniqueness_of_solutions)).